# Is there still a ~64 local notification limit for the new UserNotifications in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios10, usernotifications

In everything before iOS 9 there was a limit of 64 notifications that could be scheduled at any one time. Is this still true with the new notification system or can I schedule as many in advance as I'd like with the new UNUserNotifications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. I just updated an app of mine that schedules a lot of local notifications and the 64 limit is still in place.

Comment: great to hear (or not so great), thanks for the response.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilocalnotification I don't see the same limit documented with the new push notification APIs, but in testing, I wasn't able to schedule more than 64 (iOS 10). I haven't checked on the iOS 11 betas yet.

Comment: Hi @ChadPodoski, did you work around this limitation to add more notifications in your app?

Comment: The only way I found to work around it was to make the last notification or two something to tell the user that the app needs to be opened. I've been meaning to look into whether I could make that last notification a recurring one as well ... which I think should be possible ... so they might get an 'Please open the app to start getting notifications again' push notification likes once a week for example.